# derivative exist almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration, differential

I am working on a problem finding an error of an example that uses integration by parts.

The condition of the example says that $f'$ and $g'$ exist almost everywhere.

If $f'$ and $g'$ exist almost everywhere, does this condition implies that $f'$ and $g'$ are Riemann integrable? What I want to argue is that they are not, since $f'$ and $g'$ may not be continuous a.e..

Also, I recall that $f$, $g$ must be differentiable (I suspect this condition is stronger than $f'$ and $g'$ exist a.e.) in order to use integration by part. Can this be a reason for why integration by part is not working on the example that I am working on?

Comment: You're right.  As an example, [The Volterra Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) is differentiable, its derivative is bounded, but the derivative is not Riemann integrable.